# Oracle APEX Database Trigger - Problems with referencing database columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I have a colon delimited list of values being stored in a `varchar2` column, `ORDER_PARTS_LIST`, of my Oracle database.

*(I understand that storing data in a list like this might not be best practice but for now just ignore that fact.)*

Here are the relevant table columns:

```
 ORDER_TABLE(
    ORDER_NUMBER number,
    ORDER_PARTS_LIST varchar(4000))

 PARTS_TABLE(
    PART_NUMBER varchar(20),
    ASSIGNED_ORDER_NUMBER number)
```

I have a conditional trigger:

```
 create or replace trigger "ORDER_PARTS_T1"
 BEFORE
 insert or update or delete on "ORDER_TABLE"
 for each row
 begin
   if :new.ORDER_PARTS_LIST LIKE '%'+PART_NUMBER+'%' then
     update PARTS_TABLE set ASSIGNED_ORDER_NUMBER = :ORDER_NUMBER;   
   end if;

 end;
```

When I run this trigger I get the following error:

```
 PLS-00201: identifier 'PART_NUMBER' must be declared
```

What is supposed to happen is that the trigger checks which `PART_NUMBERs`, in `PARTS_TABLE`, are included in the `ORDER_PARTS_LIST`, in the `ORDER_TABLE`, and then inserts the `ORDER_NUMBER`, for the affected row in `ORDER_TABLE`, into the `ASSIGNED_ORDER_NUMBER` column, of `PARTS_TABLE`.

In the end, all the PARTS in an ORDER should be flagged with that ORDER's NUMBER.

Does that make ANY sense???

I am not certain exactly how to properly define the variables in this trigger so that it runs and honestly I have a few doubts as to whether or not the trigger would do what I think it should even if those worked. ANY suggestions or help in getting the trigger functioing like I have defined it should would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do string matching to test each row:

```
create or replace trigger "ORDER_PARTS_T1"
BEFORE
insert or update on "ORDER_TABLE"
for each row
begin
  update PARTS_TABLE p
  set p.ASSIGNED_ORDER_NUMBER = :new.ORDER_NUMBER
  where instr(':' || :new.ORDER_PARTS_LIST || ':'
             ,':' || p.PART_NUMBER || ':') > 0;
end;
```

So for example, if ORDER_PARTS_LIST is `'123:456:789'`, the INSTR will find matches for the ids 123, 456 and 789, but not 124, 45 or 8, for example.

When parts are removed from an order you will need a different trigger to `NULL` the appropriate fields in `PARTS_TABLE`:

```
create or replace trigger "ORDER_PARTS_T1"
BEFORE
update on "ORDER_TABLE"
for each row
begin
  update PARTS_TABLE p
  set p.ASSIGNED_ORDER_NUMBER = NULL
  where instr(':' || :new.ORDER_PARTS_LIST || ':'
             ,':' || p.PART_NUMBER || ':') = 0
  and instr(':' || :old.ORDER_PARTS_LIST || ':'
             ,':' || p.PART_NUMBER || ':') > 0;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Just as a kind of follow up... you mentioned delete and I think you are correct there is really no reason for that to have been included as records will likely not be deleted from the database. There is a possibility however that PART_NUMBERS could be removed from an ORDER prior to it being sent for processing. Is there an easy way to update the PARTS_TABLE to account for if a part has been removed from an order? Would I need a seperate trigger using OLD & NEW etc?

Comment: The 2nd trigger works great! Thanks so much! I have noticed an issue with the first trigger however... I am not sure if my tests were just simply using update (where it works great) but the initial insert/creation of the order does not cause the parts in PARTS_TABLE to be tagged. I have been trying to fix the issue but to no avail. I can find no reason for it to work on update but not on insert. Thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to provide further info, do some more investigation, perhaps add logging to the trigger. Is the trigger firing on insert? Is ORDER_NUMBER and ORDER_PARTS_LIST not null? Do the relevant rows in PARTS_TABLE exist *at the point in time* when the trigger fires? Does it work if you execute the insert manually in SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a trigger on the ORDER_TABLE. Since the ORDER_TABLE does not contain a column named PART_NUMBER, Oracle is unable to find the identifier 'PART_NUMBER' as it belongs to the PARTS_TABLE.

You will need to write a separate query in your trigger to access the PART_NUMBER in PARTS_TABLE.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure how this all fits together (seems like this won't account for the same part on multiple orders), but it looks like what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
 create or replace trigger "ORDER_PARTS_T1"
 BEFORE
 insert or update or delete on "ORDER_TABLE"
 for each row
 begin
    update parts_table
    set assigned_order_number = :new.ORDER_NUMBER
    where part_number in (:new.order_parts_list);
 end;
```

Comment: Hmmm... it seems to work if only one part_number has been selected but if multiples have been selected it does not. It doesnt throw errors but it just doesnt write the values.

Comment: @Danimal37, unfortunately you can't expect the IN statement to magically turn a single parameter (`:new.order_parts_list`) into an in-list as you might expect. That's why it will only work if only a single value has been selected.

Comment: Right... you'd probably need to wrap each element in single quotes for that to work correctly.